# creating a new variable using dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new variable using dplyr in R

Here is the data -

```
    year  TICKER   auditor_fkey  pauditor_fkey  AUDTURNOVER
1  2001    AIR            4            NA          NA
2  2002    AIR            4             4           0
3  2003    AIR            4             4           0
4  2004    AIR            4             4           0
5  2005    AIR            4             4           0
6  2006    AIR            4             4           0
7  2007    AIR            4             4           0
8  2008    AIR            4             4           0
9  2009    AIR            4             4           0
10 2010    AIR            4             4           0
11 2011    AIR            4             4           0
12 2012    AIR            4             4           0
13 2013    AIR            4             4           0
14 2014    AIR            4             4           0
15 2015    AIR            4             4           0
16 2016    AIR            4             4           0
17 2017    AIR            4             4           0
18 2000    ABT            5            NA          NA
19 2001    ABT            5             5           0
20 2002    ABT            3             5           1
21 2003    ABT            3             3           0
22 2004    ABT            3             3           0
23 2005    ABT            3             3           0
24 2006    ABT            3             3           0
25 2007    ABT            3             3           0
26 2008    ABT            3             3           0
27 2009    ABT            3             3           0
28 2010    ABT            3             3           0
29 2011    ABT            3             3           0
30 2012    ABT            3             3           0
31 2013    ABT            3             3           0
32 2014    ABT            2             3           1
33 2015    ABT            2             2           0
34 2016    ABT            2             2           0
35 2017    ABT            2             2           0
36 2007   WDDD          598            NA           0
37 2008   WDDD          598           598           0
38 2009   WDDD          598           598           0
39 2010   WDDD          598           598           0
40 2011   WDDD          598           598           0
41 2012   WDDD          598           598           0
42 2013   WDDD          598           598           0
43 2014   WDDD          598           598           0
44 2015   WDDD        27105           598           1
45 2016   WDDD        27105         27105           0
46 2017   WDDD        27105         27105           0
47 2001   ACET            4            NA          NA
48 2002   ACET            4             4           0
49 2003   ACET            4             4           0
50 2004   ACET            4             4           0
51 2005   ACET            4             4           0
52 2006   ACET            7             4           1
53 2007   ACET            7             7           0
54 2008   ACET            7             7           0
55 2009   ACET            7             7           0
56 2010   ACET        11761             7           1
57 2011   ACET        11761         11761           0
58 2012   ACET        11761         11761           0
59 2013   ACET        11761         11761           0
60 2014   ACET        11761         11761           0
61 2015   ACET        11761         11761           0
62 2016   ACET        11761         11761           0
63 2017   ACET        11761         11761           0
64 2000    ACU            2            NA          NA
65 2001    ACU            2             2           0
66 2002    ACU            2             2           0
67 2003    ACU            2             2           0
68 2004    ACU            2             2           0
69 2005    ACU            2             2           0
70 2006    ACU            2             2           0
71 2007    ACU            2             2           0
72 2008    ACU         1687             2           1
73 2008    ACU            2          1687           1
74 2009    ACU         1687             2           1
75 2010    ACU         8256          1687           1
76 2011    ACU         8256          8256           0
77 2012    ACU         8256          8256           0
78 2013    ACU         8256          8256           0
79 2014    ACU         8256          8256           0
80 2015    ACU         8256          8256           0
81 2016    ACU         8256          8256           0
82 2017    ACU         8256          8256           0
```

I created the "pauditor_fkey" variable, using the following code

```
my_data <- my_data%>%
  group_by(TICKER) %>% 
  mutate(pauditor_fkey = lag (auditor_fkey))
```

Here,
 year = a year;
 TICKER = identifier of a company;
 auditor_fkey = identified of the auditor who audited the company in a year (e.g., auditor "4"  audited company "AIR" in "2001);
 pauditor_fkey = the auditor in the previous year;
 AUDTURNOVER = if in a particular year, a auditor changes I code them 1, otherwise 0.

Now, I want to create a new variable called **AUDITOR_TENURE**, using the above variables

After running the code, the data should look like this -

```
   year  TICKER   auditor_fkey   pauditor_fkey  AUDTURNOVER  AUDITOR_TENURE
1  2001    AIR            4            NA          NA              1
2  2002    AIR            4             4           0              2
3  2003    AIR            4             4           0              3
4  2004    AIR            4             4           0              4
5  2005    AIR            4             4           0              5
6  2006    AIR            4             4           0              6
7  2007    AIR            4             4           0              7
8  2008    AIR            4             4           0              8
9  2009    AIR            4             4           0              9
10 2010    AIR            4             4           0             10
11 2011    AIR            4             4           0             11
12 2012    AIR            4             4           0             12
13 2013    AIR            4             4           0             13
14 2014    AIR            4             4           0             14
15 2015    AIR            4             4           0             15
16 2016    AIR            4             4           0             16
17 2017    AIR            4             4           0             17
18 2000    ABT            5            NA          NA              1
19 2001    ABT            5             5           0              2
20 2002    ABT            3             5           1              1
21 2003    ABT            3             3           0              2
22 2004    ABT            3             3           0              3
23 2005    ABT            3             3           0              4
24 2006    ABT            3             3           0              5
25 2007    ABT            3             3           0              6
26 2008    ABT            3             3           0              7
27 2009    ABT            3             3           0              8
28 2010    ABT            3             3           0              9
29 2011    ABT            3             3           0             10
30 2012    ABT            3             3           0             11
31 2013    ABT            3             3           0             12
32 2014    ABT            2             3           1              1
33 2015    ABT            2             2           0              2
34 2016    ABT            2             2           0              3
35 2017    ABT            2             2           0              4
36 2007   WDDD          598            NA           0              1
37 2008   WDDD          598           598           0              2
38 2009   WDDD          598           598           0              3
39 2010   WDDD          598           598           0              4
40 2011   WDDD          598           598           0              5
41 2012   WDDD          598           598           0              6
42 2013   WDDD          598           598           0              7
43 2014   WDDD          598           598           0              8
44 2015   WDDD        27105           598           1              1
45 2016   WDDD        27105         27105           0              2
46 2017   WDDD        27105         27105           0              3
47 2001   ACET            4            NA          NA              1
48 2002   ACET            4             4           0              2
49 2003   ACET            4             4           0              3
50 2004   ACET            4             4           0              4
51 2005   ACET            4             4           0              5
52 2006   ACET            7             4           1              1
53 2007   ACET            7             7           0              2
54 2008   ACET            7             7           0              3
55 2009   ACET            7             7           0              4
56 2010   ACET        11761             7           1              1
57 2011   ACET        11761         11761           0              2
58 2012   ACET        11761         11761           0              3
59 2013   ACET        11761         11761           0              4
60 2014   ACET        11761         11761           0              5
61 2015   ACET        11761         11761           0              6
62 2016   ACET        11761         11761           0              7
63 2017   ACET        11761         11761           0              8
64 2000    ACU            2            NA          NA              1
65 2001    ACU            2             2           0              2
66 2002    ACU            2             2           0              3
67 2003    ACU            2             2           0              4
68 2004    ACU            2             2           0              5
69 2005    ACU            2             2           0              6
70 2006    ACU            2             2           0              7
71 2007    ACU            2             2           0              8
72 2008    ACU         1687             2           1              1
73 2008    ACU            2          1687           1              1
74 2009    ACU         1687             2           1              1
75 2010    ACU         8256          1687           1              1
76 2011    ACU         8256          8256           0              2
77 2012    ACU         8256          8256           0              3
78 2013    ACU         8256          8256           0              4
79 2014    ACU         8256          8256           0              5
80 2015    ACU         8256          8256           0              6
81 2016    ACU         8256          8256           0              7
82 2017    ACU         8256          8256           0              8
```

if the **AUDITOR_TENURE**  variable is inspected, it is seen that 
for TICKER == AIR, there was no change in the auditor; so, the **AUDITOR_TENURE**
increases. For TICKER == ABT, it is seen that for years 2000 and 2001, there was no change of the auditor; so the **AUDITOR_TENURE** is 1 and 2 respectively for those years for that auditor. However, in 2002, there was a change in auditor for ABT and that auditor continues to work until 2013 and therefore for them new number is generated for **AUDITOR_TENURE** variable. Then in 2015, they change auditor again and the auditor continues work until 2017 and their tenure is calculated accordingly.

I am actually looking for R code for this problem.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: what do you want the variable to be? also you're missing a bracket after audiot_fkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `group_by` `TICKER` and `auditor_fkey` and assign `row_number()` to each group

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

my_data %>%
  group_by(TICKER, group = rleid(auditor_fkey)) %>%
  mutate(AUDITOR_TENURE = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#    year TICKER auditor_fkey pauditor_fkey AUDTURNOVER AUDITOR_TENURE
#   <int> <fct>         <int>         <int>       <int>          <int>
# 1  2001 AIR               4            NA          NA              1
# 2  2002 AIR               4             4           0              2
# 3  2003 AIR               4             4           0              3
# 4  2004 AIR               4             4           0              4
# 5  2005 AIR               4             4           0              5
# 6  2006 AIR               4             4           0              6
# 7  2007 AIR               4             4           0              7
# 8  2008 AIR               4             4           0              8
# 9  2009 AIR               4             4           0              9
#10  2010 AIR               4             4           0             10
# … with 72 more rows
```

---

Using only `dplyr` we can use `lag`

```
df %>%
  group_by(TICKER, group = cumsum(auditor_fkey != 
                   lag(auditor_fkey, default = first(auditor_fkey)))) %>%
  mutate(AUDITOR_TENURE = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)
```

Comment: Hi @ Ronak: Thank you very much for your quick response. when I post the data set here, I just filter out a small portion of it. When I run your code for the FULL data set, then I got different number. I believe it is because of the row_number() function because in the Full data set the row number is different from my posted data set. Do you know how can I make it independent of row_number? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Sharif The main part is `group_by`, the number should be created right if groups are made correct. Which part did you omit?

Comment: I did not omit any part. I use your code exactly. I am not sure when we use ~~~group_by (TICKER)~~~ for the Full data set, whether it groups the data in order of **year** variable. Because in my posted data the variable **year** is ordered.

Comment: I run your second code. It gives me the same answer.

Comment: Hi @ Ronak: I figure it out. Actually, you are right; the issue was in ~group_by(TICKER)~. I have NAs in TICKER; if I take NAs out and run your code, it works well. Thank you very much for your help.